# How to pass a BigDecimal to a custom taglib (WebSphere)

Tags: java, jsp, websphere, taglib

I have a custom taglib which I try to give BigDecimal to, but the scale isn't kept. It seems like the BigDecimal is converted to a double, then back to a BigDecimal. Is this a bug in WebSphere? or am I missing something?

My controller (I'm using Spring):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/BigDecimalTest")
public class BigDecimalTestController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String display(final Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("bigDecimal", new BigDecimal("126.58"));
        return "bigDecimalTest";
    }

}
```

My JSP:

```
<%@taglib uri="/custom-taglibs/bigDecimal.tld" prefix="bd"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>BigDecimal Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<bd:display value="${bigDecimal}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

My taglib descriptor:

```
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
  <description>BigDecimal test</description>
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <short-name>bd</short-name>
  <tag>
    <description>Display informations about a BigDecimal</description>
    <name>display</name>
    <tag-class>BigDecimalDisplay</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
    <attribute>
      <name>value</name>
      <required>true</required>
      <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
      <type>java.math.BigDecimal</type>
    </attribute>
  </tag>
</taglib>
```

My tag class:

```
public class BigDecimalDisplay extends TagSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2049900195699675393L;

    private BigDecimal value;

    public void setValue(final BigDecimal value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        final JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
        try {
            out.print("<div>");
            out.print("<div>Value: ");
            out.print(value.toPlainString());
            out.print("</div>");
            out.print("<div>Scale: ");
            out.print(value.scale());
            out.print("</div>");
            out.print("</div>");
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new JspException(e);
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }

}
```

Expected output:

> Value: 126.58
>   Scale: 2

Actual output:

> Value: 126.5799999999999982946974341757595539093017578125
>   Scale: 46

**Edit:** I was able to reproduce this issue without using Spring. Since obourgain could not reproduce it on Jetty, it now really seems to be a WebSphere bug.

**Edit:** Could this be IBM bug [PM48569](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PM48569)?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the bug in my application. I've created the same tag as yours, with the same taglib definition. The tag displays "value 126.58" and "scale 2" as expected. My app runs with Jetty and don't use Spring.

Comment: @obourgain Interesting. So this would be a WebSphere or a Spring bug.

Answer (score 0):

mr.
Probably you can make something like a patern if you know how many decimals you want.
link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html
I hope this will help you.
Gr. Gilian

Comment: Actually, I do not know the number of decimals. The scale is set in the BigDecimal and I am suppose to keep it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's a messy way. Ofcourse there's no problem of converting the value the way you want it, the question is why this conversion is happening and how to prevent it. You're fighting symptoms instead of fixing the actual issue ;)